# How do I beat U/R control with Affinity?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-modern

I play affinity and seriously struggle with control players and can't seem to find a way to win.

Blue Moon has become popular recently, and while [Blood Moon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Blood%20Moon) does not cripple my deck the constant counters to anything I do just stagnate the game.

[Kolaghan's Command](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=394613) kills 2 artifacts at once, normally a [Mox Opal](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mox%20Opal) and creature.

My damage cards ([Arcbound Ravager](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Arcbound%20Ravager), [Etched Champion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Etched%20Champion), [Cranial Plating](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cranial%20Plating)) are countered with spells like [Mana Leak](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mana%20Leak).

My creatures are constantly hit with [Lightning Bolt](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lightning%20Bolt), and [Jace, Telepath Unbound](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Jace%2C%20Telepath%20Unbound) and [Snapcaster Mage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Snapcaster%20Mage) lets them replay them. My land are also destroyed this way if I try to use them as creatures.

What strategy's can be used against a deck that mainboards more removal than I have playable cards and after the first round can add in specific artifact hate ?

> #### Decklist
>
> 2x [master of etherium](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=master%20of%20etherium)
> 3x [signal pest](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=signal%20pest)
> 3x [etched champion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=etched%20champion)
> 4x [arcbound ravager](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=arcbound%20ravager)
> 4x [ornithopter](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=ornithopter)
> 4x [memnite](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=memnite)
> 4x [vault skirge](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=vault%20skirge)
>
> 4x [galvanic blast](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=galvanic%20blast)
> 4x [thoughtcast](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=thoughtcast)
> 4x [mox opal](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=mox%20opal)
> 4x [spring-leaf drum](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=spring-leaf%20drum)
> 4x [cranial plating](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=cranial%20plating)
>
> 4x [darksteel citadel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=darksteel%20citadel)
> 4x [inkmoth nexus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=inkmoth%20nexus)
> 4x [blinkmoth nexus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=blinkmoth%20nexus)
> 3x [glimmervoid](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=glimmervoid)
> 1x [island](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=island)
>
> #### Sideboard
>
> 4x [spellskite](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=spellskite)
> 1x [steel overseer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=steel%20overseer)
> 1x [torpor orb](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=torpor%20orb)
> 1x [tormod's crypt](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=tormod%27s%20crypt)
> 2x [gitaxian probe](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=gitaxian%20probe)
> 4x [shrapnel blast](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=shrapnel%20blast)
> 1x [blood moon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=blood%20moon)
> 1x [glimmervoid](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=glimmervoid)

Comment: Electrolyze ("~ deals 2 damage divided as you choose among one or two target creatures and/or players. Draw a card.") can't kill a Mox Opal, fyi. So maybe in that particular context your opponent misplayed or cheated.

Comment: It destroys an artifact and deal 2 damage to creature, thought that was electrolyse but must be a diffent card.

Comment: You must be thinking of Kolaghan's Command, but that can't be run in U/R. Are you having trouble with Jund as well? They too run a lot of removal.

Comment: Skeith can you post a link to your decklist? Some of the things you're saying make it seem like you're running a very nonstandard Affinity list, and the feedback you'll get will be based on standard Affinity, so it may not be that useful to you.

Comment: Can you post a link to an example UR control decklist? U/R cannot usually cast Kolaghan's Command, so it feels like something's off.

Answer (score 1):

The answer really is to *go fast*. I say this as a long time UR player in Modern. By go fast, I mean you want to pressure your opponent's life total and build big creatures.

It looks like you have Master of Etherium in the main. That's a great card for you because it can often push your creatures out of [Pyroclasm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pyroclasm) or [Anger of the Gods](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Anger%20of%20the%20Gods) range. UR decks are typically Snap/Bolt decks. They rely heavily on damage based removal, so if you can bump your creatures out of that range (~ 3-4 toughness), you'll be doing the most good. Etched Champion has protection from just about any removal UR has, aside from countering it. If you can land an Etched Champion you are in very good position.

Holding double black up to re-equip Cranial Plating at instead speed may be difficult, but it's a great way to get around targeted removal during the combat phase. They shoot your equipped Vault Skirge? Re-equip it onto your Ornithopter.

If you want to play around counterspells, be aware of what the opponent has already played that game (and round) and take note of their open mana. They have one blue open and haven't played [Spell Snare](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Spell%20Snare) all game? Don't play your 2-drop. You can also try waiting to play multiple spells per turn. Counterspells will typically cost more mana to play than your creatures will, so even if a creature or two of yours gets countered save your best for last to get it on the board.

Lastly, most blue decks (and UR especially) tend to board out counterspells against fast decks like affinity. They often bring things in like [Shatterstorm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shatterstorm), so don't over-commit to the board. Be weary of sweepers as well.

You are always the beatdown in this matchup, UR doesn't have [Splinter Twin](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Splinter%20Twin) anymore, so as long as you can keep dropping threats you will likely come out on top.

Answer (score 0):

The card you're probably having problems with is [Kolaghan's Command](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kolaghan%27s%20Command). But, that spell is 3 cmc, so the earliest they can do it is turn 3. If you're ramping up properly, by turn 3 you should be able to handle it.

Affinity is supposed to be fast, so if you don't have the possibility of turn 1: Land, mox opal, [springleaf drum](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=springleaf%20drum), 0-drop creature, [Cranial Plating](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cranial%20Plating), you're probably too slow.

Barring that, fight fire with fire: run a couple [Dispel](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dispel) or other counters. If you don't want to go that route, a card like [Cavern of Souls](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cavern%20of%20Souls) can make some of your creatures uncounterable. [Aether Vial](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Aether%20Vial) can help you flash in creatures and dodge most counters

Comment: cavern of souls affects only 1 creture type chosen as played, no 2 creatures share a type in my deck. not very good

Comment: @Skeith That might not matter that much. Bloom Titan decks used to run Cavern of Souls and it only had one creature in the entire deck. If it's that important to your win strategy that a certain creature be in play, having one or two in the deck might not be a terrible idea. Having said that, I haven't played Modern since before Splinter Twin was banned, so the meta is probably very different.

Comment: a play set of caverns of souls is £100+, i know modern costs money but if im spending that kind of money i want better than "it might help".

Comment: [Affinity decks](http://www.mtggoldfish.com/archetype/modern-affinity-8972#online) seem not to run Cavern of Souls. But the reason is more that it can't cast Galvanic Blast or sideboard cards like Blood Moon (whereas Glimmervoid can), not so much a lack of creatures that share a type. @SocioMatt makes a great point that including Cavern to make one critical creature uncounterable, when counterspells are a major threat to the deck, is a totally valid strategy.

Comment: @Skeith You can always playtest with proxies before making the investement for tournament play. This is even encouraged by Wizards, believe it or not...